# Trying to compute Kernel of a linear functional.

Tags: continuity, operator-theory

Currently I'm reading Corollary $9.4.2$ from the book titled operator spaces by Effros and Ruan.  Given operator spaces $V$ and $W$, a linear functional $$F: V \otimes^h W \to \mathcal{C}$$
is bounded linear functional if and only if there exist a Hilbert space $H$ and completely bounded mappings $\phi: V \to B(H, \mathbb{C}) $ and $\psi: W \to B(\mathbb{C}, H) $ such that $$F(v \otimes w) = \phi(v) \psi(w) $$ I am trying to compute kernel of $F$. It is clear that $Ker(\phi) \otimes^h W + V \otimes^h Ker(\psi) \subset Ker(F) $

> Is it true that $$Ker(F)=Ker(\phi) \otimes^h W + V \otimes^h Ker(\psi) $$

Any ideas to obtain the reverse inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it true that $$\ker(F)=\ker(\phi) \otimes^h W + V \otimes^h \ker(\psi) $$

No.

Let $V=W=\mathbb C$, $H=\mathbb C^2$. Let $\phi,\psi$ be the linear maps
$$
\phi(v)(\alpha e_1+\beta e_2)=v\,\alpha,\qquad\qquad \psi(w)(\lambda)=w\lambda\,e_2.
$$
Then
$$
\ker(\phi) \otimes^h W + V \otimes^h \ker(\psi)=\{0\},
$$
since $\phi$ and $\psi$ are injective, while $\ker F=V\otimes W$.